# Only one of my ports is working as defined in my Nginx config

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, ubuntu-14.04

My server is only working for the website that is defined on port 8000 (MY.IP.AD.DRESS:8000) and not the site defined on port 8888. My Nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
listen 8000 default_server;
listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/my-follow-up/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name http://64.46.53.164/;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
}

server {
listen 8888;
listen [::]:8888 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/my-follow-up-external/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name http://64.46.53.164/;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I have given both of the root directories the correct user permissions. When I attempt to navigate to MY.IP.AD.DRESS:8888 I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, I wasn't thinking to straight.

I cannot use port 8888. Switched it to 8080 and it works fine.